# Partitioned table BigQuery (with custom field)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I can't find any examples that show how to write a JSON for a partitioned table using a custom field. Below is an example of how to specify a table partitioned by the type "DAY", but if I, in addition, would like to partition by a specific field - how would the JSON look like?

```
{
  "tableReference": {
    "projectId": "bookstore-1382",
    "datasetId": "exports",
    "tableId": "partition"
  },
  "timePartitioning": {
    "type": "DAY"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [API reference](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tables#timePartitioning). The `timePartitioning` object currently supports the following attributes:

- `expirationMs`
- `field`
- `requirePartitionFilter`
- `type`

I won't copy/paste all of the comments here, but this is what it says for `field`:

> [Experimental] [Optional] If not set, the table is partitioned by
>   pseudo column '_PARTITIONTIME'; if set, the table is partitioned by
>   this field. The field must be a top-level TIMESTAMP or DATE field. Its
>   mode must be NULLABLE or REQUIRED.

In your case, the payload would look like:

```
{
  "tableReference": {
    "projectId": "<your project>",
    "datasetId": "<your dataset>",
    "tableId": "partition"
  },
  "timePartitioning": {
    "type": "DAY",
    "field": "<date_or_timestamp_column_name>"
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you can issue a [`CREATE TABLE` DDL statement](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/data-definition-language#create_table_statement) using standard SQL. To give an example:

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TABLE `your-project.your-dataset.table`
(
  x INT64,
  event_date DATE
)
PARTITION BY event_date;
```